# reading wav files in all subdirectories

Tags: python, io, scipy, wav

I want to read all the wav files using scipy.io.wavfile module in the subdirectories of my main directory.

```
r_dir='/home/deepthought/Music/genres/'
import os
import scipy.io.wavfile
data = []
rate = []
for root,sub,files in os.walk(r_dir):
    files = sorted(files)
    for f in files:
        s_rate, x  =  scipy.io.wavfile.read(f)
        rate.append(s_rate)
        data.append(x)
```

Understandably, this code doesn't work as 'files' only has the file name. That is why I am getting the error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py", line 151, in read
fid = open(filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hiphop.00000.au.wav'
```

How to I get the complete path for each file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `root` with `f` to get proper file path using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
for root, sub, files in os.walk(r_dir):
    files = sorted(files)
    for f in files:
        s_rate, x  =  scipy.io.wavfile.read(os.path.join(root, f))  # <---
        rate.append(s_rate)
        data.append(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `os.chdir(root)` in for loop as:

```
for f in files:
    os.chdir(root)  # move to the directory where files are present
    s_rate, x  =  scipy.io.wavfile.read(f)
    rate.append(s_rate)
    data.append(x)
```

Another way is to join file name with its path using `os.psth.join()` as:

```
for f in files:
    s_rate, x  =  scipy.io.wavfile.read(os.path.join(root,f))  # join path with filename
    rate.append(s_rate)
    data.append(x)
```

Comment: 1) `os.chdir(root)` can be out of the loop. (before the `for` loop)  2) changing directory is risky, especially if the root directory is relative path, it will prevent `os.walk` recursion to work correctly.

Comment: Marked the other one as correct as it seems more versatile.